# How to get "numFound" using JSON query for Solr?

Tags: javascript, json, solr, response

I am simply trying to obtain the **"numFound"** figure from a Solr query in a piece of javascript.

At present the code I have outputs the number of responses, limited to X rows I specify, as well as X number of items.

**What I want instead is the "numFound" value in the response, and to store it as a var in my javascript.**

In the example below it would be 394.

```
    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":31,
    "params":{
      "q":"names:\"Leo Varadkar\" AND region:\"ROI\""}},
  "response":{"numFound":394,"start":0,"maxScore":11.911881,"docs":[
```

I don't want any info from the fields of a specific entry or anything like that. In my python code I can obtain such a figure by something like "`solr.search(query).hits`". However I have been unable to find an equivalent from poking around with this. I have tried to guess something like "data.response.hits" and the like but to no avail. I am really in the dark here!

I have been unable to find clear documentation on how to do this, or an example of someone doing the same thing, despite it seeming like quite an important aspect of the whole point of queries in Solr. Top 50 results are no use to me. I am dealing with tens of thousands of items. My confusion might suggest I am failing to understand some key aspect of the whole thing...but I don't think so?

All I want is that figure. Surely somebody knows how to get it? I bet it's very simple.

My javascript below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function on_data(data) {
    $('#results').empty();
    var docs = data.response.docs;
    $.each(docs, function(i, item) {
        $('#results').prepend($('<div>' + item.name + '</div>'));
    });

    var hits = 'Found ' + data.response. + ' hits'
    $('#hits').prepend('<div>' + hits + '</div>');

    var total = 'Found ' + docs.length + ' results';
    $('#results').prepend('<div>' + total + '</div>');
}

function on_search() {
    var query = $('#query').val();
    if (query.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    var url='http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/select?q=text:'+query+'&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10000&indent=on&wt=json&callback=?&json.wrf=on_data';
    var urlB='http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/select?q=text:'+query+'&version=2.2&start=0&rows=50&indent=on&wt=json&callback=?&json.wrf=on_data';
    $.getJSON(urlB);
}

function on_ready() {
    $('#search').click(on_search);
    /* Hook enter to search */
    $('body').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '13') {
            on_search();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(on_ready);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure is `{"response":{"numFound":394 ... }}`, which is loaded into your `data` variable.

```
var hits = 'Found ' + data.response.numFound + ' hits'
```

.. should give you the number you're looking for. The `hits` name is just given by various libraries (probably pysolr in your case) to the same value.

You can also use `console.log(data)` to see the parsed data structure in your developer tools' console window.

Comment: Brilliant that's exactly what I was looking for. I think I typed that already but got put off when Pycharm didn't light it up blue, as I wasn't very sure of myself. Working perfectly now.